# Performing nested boolean queries within another boolean query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want do nest a boolean query with multiple must/should inside another boolean query to get a nested AND/OR query string like in the following query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        **// SHOULD BLOCK 1**
        {
          <should_query_1>
        },
        **// SHOULD BLOCK 2**
        {
          <should_query_2>
        },
        **// SHOULD BLOCK 3**
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              <should_level_2_MUST_query_1>,
              <should_level_2_MUST_query_2>,
          {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            <should_level_3_MUST_query_1>,
            <should_level_3_MUST_query_2>,
          ]         
        }
          }
            ]
          }
        },
        **// SHOULD BLOCK 4**
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              <should_MUST_query_1>,
              <should_MUST_query_2>
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 25,
  "from": 0,
  "fields": []
}
```

The expected behavior is, I want the should blocks 1,2,3,4 'OR'ed and within the "should block 3" i want the "Should_level_2_MUST_queries" to be 'AND'ed.

But in reality When i am using this syntax the should blocks 3 & 4 are 'AND'ed in the first level itself and ORed with blocks 1 & 2. Please help me rearrange/ rewrite this query for me the achieve the expected behaviour.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, elasticsearch dont have and/or levels like the one in boolean algebra. At the end there is always one level.

So, in your query, you basically say that "I need 3 must query", so those 3 must queries' combined result will be in the final response.

If I understood it correctly, to reach expected behavior, you should do following:

- Convert all musts to should
- If you need AND put those shoulds `"minumum_should_match:N"` rule where N is an integer

Guides:

- [How to use minumum should match?](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html)